# Accessing webelement of previous page in history throws error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a website to be scraped with 4 levels of nested pages.

```
Level 1
    --->Level 2
        --->Level 3
            --->Level 4
        --->Level 3
            --->Level 4
    --->Level 2
```

Hence, I have to visit back and forth to visit each Level 4, of each Level 3, of each Level 2, of each Level 1.

Hence, I created nested loops

```
List<WebElement> chapters = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[*]/td[3]/a"));
        for(WebElement chapter: chapters)
        {
            String chapter_name = chapter.getText();
            String chapter_url = chapter.getAttribute("href");

            System.out.println("CHAPTER : " + chapter_name + "URL : " + chapter_url);
            driver.get(chapter_url);

            List<WebElement> topics = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[*]/td[3]/a"));
            for(WebElement topic: topics)
            {
                String topic_name = topic.getText();
                String topic_url = topic.getAttribute("href");

                System.out.println("\tTOPIC : " + topic_name +  "URL : " + topic_url);
                driver.get(topic_url);
                List<WebElement> sub_topics = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[*]/td[3]/a"));
                for(WebElement sub_topic : sub_topics)
                {
                    String sub_topic_name = sub_topic.getText();
                    String sub_topic_url = sub_topic.getAttribute("href");

                    System.out.println("\t\tSUBTOPIC : " + sub_topic_name + "URL : " + sub_topic_url);
                    driver.get(sub_topic_url);
                    List<WebElement> problems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[*]/td[3]/a"));
                    for(WebElement problem : problems)
                    {
                        System.out.println("\t\t\t"+problem.getText());
                    }
                    driver.navigate().back();
                }
                driver.navigate().back();
            }
            driver.navigate().back();
        }
```

But I get the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Web element reference not seen before: dcbb0aef-d165-4450-964c-535fc4577f69
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'
System info: host: 'workstation', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-39-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 63.0.3, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.23.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 13651, moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofile.gx46rW..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 4.15.0-39-generic, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 55d3e16e-5920-414d-b047-a24f5483a2c7
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:276)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getText(RemoteWebElement.java:160)
    at firstTest.Getlinks.main(Getlinks.java:52)
```

This is perhaps because navigating back might be a refresh and the state is lost. What's the solution/best practice in such cases?

Comment: One obvious solution is I store the URLs instead of Elements in the List, but still that's less intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely navigating back. Each time you navigate back you got a new page and previously stored elements are no longer interactable. I noticed that all your xPathes are to take links (and, by the way, they are similar), so here's how I modified the code that potentially might solve your problem:

```
private static final By XPATH = By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[*]/td[3]/a");

    public void testMethod() {
        List<WebElement> chapters = driver.findElements(XPATH);
        List<String> chapterTexts = getTextsFromElements(chapters);

        scanChapters(chapterTexts);
    }

    private List<String> getTextsFromElements(List<WebElement> els) {
        List<String> texts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (WebElement el : els) {
            texts.add(el.getText());
        }
        return texts;
    }

    private void scanChapters(List<String> chapterTexts) {
        for (String chapterText : chapterTexts) {
            WebElement chapter = driver.findElement(By.linkText((chapterText)));
            String chapter_url = chapter.getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println("CHAPTER : " + chapterText + "URL : " + chapter_url);
            driver.get(chapter_url);

            List<WebElement> topics = driver.findElements(XPATH);
            List<String> topicTexts = getTextsFromElements(topics);
            scanTopics(topicTexts);

            driver.navigate().back();
        }
    }

    private void scanTopics(List<String> topicTexts) {
        for (String topicText : topicTexts) {
            WebElement topic = driver.findElement(By.linkText((topicText)));
            String topic_url = topic.getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println("\tTOPIC : " + topicText + "URL : " + topic_url);
            driver.get(topic_url);

            List<WebElement> sub_topics = driver.findElements(XPATH);
            List<String> subTopicTexts = getTextsFromElements(sub_topics);
            scanSubTopics(subTopicTexts);

            driver.navigate().back();
        }
    }

    private void scanSubTopics(List<String> subTopicTexts) {
        for (String subTopicText : subTopicTexts) {
            WebElement subTopic = driver.findElement(By.linkText((subTopicText)));
            String sub_topic_url = subTopic.getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println("\t\tSUBTOPIC : " + subTopicText + "URL : " + sub_topic_url);
            driver.get(sub_topic_url);

            List<WebElement> problems = driver.findElements(XPATH);
            for (WebElement problem : problems) {
                System.out.println("\t\t\t" + problem.getText());
            }

            driver.navigate().back();
        }
    }
```